# Make consecutive GET requests to API

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, get

I'm making a GET request to a URL which responds with a JSON object which has more URLs inside. the URLs inside the response I also need to make a GET request to, i'm wondering if there's a faster/alternative way to speed it up.

Currently it works like this -

Make request to URL1 > find URL2 in response > make request to URL2 > find URL3 in response > make request to URL3 and so on.....

it seems slow because the requests are one after the other.

The first response I get is like this

```
{
    "href": "URL1",
    "date": "*******",
    "message": "Test",
    "displayDepartment": true,
    "recipients": [
        {
            "href": "URL2"
        }
    ],
    "nominator": {
        "href": "notneeded"
    },
}
```

I'm making the requests in C# and looking for a way to make a request to URL1 and at the same time make a request to URL2 which is in the first ones response.

Comment: `looking for a way to make a request to URL1 and at the same time make a request to URL2 which is in the first ones response.` If Step 2 is dependent on the results of Step 1, I am unclear on how you plan to run Step 2 before Step 1 is finished? Either way, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a design decision of your API. If there is no call to get all urls at once or all objects with one request, then I don't see a chance to improve your process. Don't worry about style or reviews. If the API is given, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought, I was just wondering if there was another option I didn't know about. thanks anyway

Comment: I know that feeling. Some APIs are a real pain for developers. This one is not that bad actually. ;) (At least from what I see here)